# Maven- Error building pom

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, plexus

While trying `mvn clean install` I got the following error:

```
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-components:pom:1.1.15

Reason: Cannot find parent: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus for project: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-components:pom:1.1.15 for project org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-components:pom:1.1.15
```

The same works when I user `mvn clean install` as root user. What may be the possible reason?

Comment: Please copy paste your pom file to see that . I think there is problem in your pom file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:-

- Update maven to version 3.
- Deleted the .m2/org/codehaus folder.
- Build the project.

  Issue fixed!